# Entity Framework 4 ctp5 one table has two foreign keys to the same table

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-ctp5

I Have two tables:

Users and News. Table News has columns id, name, createdby, modifiedby. Table user has columns id and name. Table News references table User by foreign keys createdby and modifiedby. I use 
Entity Framework 4 ctp5. I tried to access createdby or modifiedby properties, but error appers: Invalid column name "UserId1", Invalid column name "UserId2". Could anybody explain what I am doing wrong?

```
public class News
{
    // Primitive properties

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid UserId1 { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }

}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class SomeEntities : DbContext
{
    public SomeEntities() : base("name=SomeEntities"){ }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<News>().Property(i => i.UserId).HasColumnName("CreatedBy");
        modelBuilder.Entity<News>().Property(i => i.UserId1).HasColumnName("ModifiedBy");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following object model gives you the desired results (I renamed properties just to make it more readable):

```
public class News
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User ModifiedByUser { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Ctp5Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<News>()
                    .HasRequired(n => n.CreatedByUser)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(n => n.CreatedBy);

        modelBuilder.Entity<News>()
                    .HasRequired(n => n.ModifiedByUser)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(n => n.ModifiedBy)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);                        
    }
}
```